# Which database engine type should be specified for Microsoft SQL Database in Laravel?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent, octobercms, database-engine

I am working on a web application using OctoberCMS which sits on Laravel 5.5.40 and is using a Microsoft SQL Database.

Database migrations are managed using the standard Blueprint objects which allow a database engine to be specified. Currently all the migrations are using InnoDB, which I believe is only supported by MySQL.

Does this mean that the engine type is being ignored? Also is it possible to specify different engine types for Microsoft SQL Database tables and what options are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of "database engine" or "storage engine" is quite specific to MySQL; most database systems have a single back end which everything is built on. There are sometimes special types of database or table for specialist circumstances - e.g. adapters for importing data from other systems, or column-oriented stores for analysing large data sets - but they're rarely encountered.

For Microsoft SQL Server, there really isn't an equivalent option you need to specify. There may be other options you can set about how to configure the table for performance, but I would expect the ORM choose reasonable defaults and there isn't a single parameter with lots of tradeoffs like changing a MySQL engine.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel (latest version at least) supports the following databases:

Currently, Laravel supports four databases types as per the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#introduction

> MySQL 5.6+, PostgreSQL 9.4+, SQLite 3.8.8+, SQL Server 2017+

Each drivers are fully compatible with Eloquent, including Migrations
Therefore, in your database config file use `'default' => 'sqlsrv',` and you should be good to go